# Updating State for unknown # of Props in Next.JS Class Components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, next.js, react-props

Let's say I want a sidebar for a live (duplex) chat client that displays all current users & updates whenever users join or exit.

User data from the API is passed in as a TS type `MemberProps` that is then be passed into a `MembersProps.members[]` array with a dynamic size.

```
type MemberProps = {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    image: string;
};

type MembersProps = {
    members: MemberProps[];
};
```

I need to update the front-end Components but want to do it in a Typescript-compliant way (no hooks, no React.FC..?).

Where should I update `MembersProps.members[]` & append/remove data from the front-end component?

Through `state`?

A `constructor`?

`componentWillMount()`?

In a function called by the `class Component`?

```
function UpdateMembers() {
  // fetch response, convert to new MemberProps
  // then push to array?
  // include logic to remove users that go offline?
}
```

```
class MembersOnline extends React.Component<MembersProps, MembersState> {

    // update MembersState && MembersProps?

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.image} {this.props.username}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or should state behavior be defined in the `Page` e.g. `pages/home` in the project directory.

**tl;dr** confused about how Components in Typescript Next.js should deal with websocket-type behavior.